# Altium footprint library

Tags: pcb-design, altium, footprint, library, 3d

I created a new PCB library in Altium. I want to add a 3D model of the component, but I don't want to download the 3D model step file of a component on my computer. Can I directly import it to my PCB Library in Altium? Can I save the 3D model of the footprint into the Altium Library without having their 3D model file in the SSD of my computer?

For instance, I want to open my project on another computer. Can I see the 3D model of the footprints that I saved on another computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import a step model into AD there is an option to embed the 3D model into the library.

Once this has been done you then no longer require the step file, but you will have to initially download it before getting AD to embed a copy into the library.